# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'format' of undefined

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to format numbers in chartjs chart. I am getting this error on my console and the numbers are not visible on the chart

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'format' of undefined

You can refer the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/prady/5mbd5m71/4/#&togetherjs=9FyGkPSFzy). Line 74 on the fiddle

```
for (var i = 0; i < firstDataSet.data.length; i++) {
                            var firstModel = firstDataSet._meta[Object.keys(firstDataSet._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
                            var secondModel = secondDataSet._meta[Object.keys(secondDataSet._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
                            var thirdModel = thirdDataSet._meta[Object.keys(thirdDataSet._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
                            var fourthModel = fourthDataSet._meta[Object.keys(fourthDataSet._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
                            var total = firstDataSet.data[i] + secondDataSet.data[i];
                            var total1 = thirdDataSet.data[i] + fourthDataSet.data[i];
   // Line below is causing the error 


 ctx.fillText(formatter.format(Number(firstDataSet.data[i])) + " ", firstModel.x, firstModel.y + 20); 

                            ctx.fillText((firstDataSet.data[i]) , firstModel.x, firstModel.y + 20);
                            ctx.fillText((secondDataSet.data[i] ) , secondModel.x, secondModel.y + 20);
                            ctx.fillText(total , secondModel.x, secondModel.y - 20);
                            ctx.fillText((thirdDataSet.data[i]) , thirdModel.x, thirdModel.y + 20);
                            ctx.fillText((fourthDataSet.data[i] ) , fourthModel.x, fourthModel.y + 20);
                            ctx.fillText(total1 , fourthModel.x, fourthModel.y - 20);
                            /*if (firstDataSet.data[i] >= secondDataSet.data[i]) {
                                ctx.fillText((firstDataSet.data[i] * 100 / total).toFixed(2) + '%', firstModel.x, firstModel.y + 30);
                            } else {
                                ctx.fillText((secondDataSet.data[i] * 100 / total).toFixed(2) + '%', secondModel.x, secondModel.y + 30);
                            }
                            */
                        }

var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  // the default value for minimumFractionDigits depends on the currency
  // and is usually already 2
});
```

Comment: Declare the `formatter` before `window.myBar = new Chart(ctx...`. Like so: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6j3L6p8s/)

Comment: Oh great.. that did it. If you can add it as an answer i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the `formatter` before calling the `new Chart` constructor function, otherwise it will be `undefined` inside the `options` you are passing as the second parameter of `new Chart`.

```
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  // the default value for minimumFractionDigits depends on the currency
  // and is usually already 2
});

window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```